# MuiPhoneNumber disables typing when error is true, react, material-ui-phone-number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm trying to follow the instructions for material-ui-phone-number for react, using material ui for react. On `onChange` I call the `handlePhone` function, which saves the value of the input to the state. Problem is, on each `setPhone`, it disables the input, like it unfocuses the input, you have to click in the input each time to type into it. If I remove `setPhone(value);`, it types fine inside, but then I'm not saving the value and losing the validation. Any ideas?

js:

```
const [phone, setPhone] = React.useState("");
const [phoneError, setPhoneError] = React.useState(false);
const handlePhone = (value, countrydata) => {
    setPhoneError(false);
    setPhone(value);
```

html:

```
<MuiPhoneNumber fullWidth defaultCountry={"es"} variant="outlined" label="Número de teléfono" name="phone" onChange={handlePhone} error={phoneError} helperText={phoneError && "Invalid phone"} value={phone} />
```

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm using a dirty solution to add `autoFocus` parameter, that changes boolean onChange

html:

```
<MuiPhoneNumber key="autofocus_issue_112" defaultCountry="es" fullWidth variant="outlined" label="Número de teléfono" name="phone" value={phone} onChange={handlePhone} error={phoneError} helperText={phoneError && "Invalid phone number"} autoFocus={focusPhone} />
```

js:

```
const [focusPhone, setFocusPhone] = React.useState(false);
     function handlePhone(value) {
        setFocusPhone(true);
        setPhone(value);
        setPhoneError(false);
      }
```

But its important to add, you need to do `setFocusPhone(false);` when the user clicks on another input field, otherwise `MuiPhoneNumber` will always be focused.